# How to implement Deref "multiple times"?

Tags: rust

I have an example from wasm-bindgen crate: [text](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.HtmlCanvasElement.html)
There are methods from many Deref implementations. Although I thought that traits with associative types could be implemented once

I have no idea how it's implemented
I don’t know, for example, what can be used as a Deref<Target = ?>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you scroll all the way down to the trait implementations, you'll see that there's only [one implementation of `Deref`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.HtmlCanvasElement.html#impl-Deref-for-HtmlCanvasElement). You can then click through and see the target also implements deref. This continues.

- `HtmlCanvasElement` implements `Deref<Target = HtmlElement>`
- `HtmlElement` implements [`Deref<Target = Element>`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.HtmlElement.html#impl-Deref-for-HtmlElement)
- `Element` implements [`Deref<Target = Node>`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.Element.html#impl-Deref-for-Element)
- `Node` implements [`Deref<Target = EventTarget>`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.Node.html#impl-Deref-for-Node)
- `EventTarget` implements [`Deref<Target = Object>`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.EventTarget.html#impl-Deref-for-EventTarget)
- `Object` implements [`Deref<Target = JsValue>`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0.3.64/js_sys/struct.Object.html#impl-Deref-for-Object)

Rustdoc lists the methods from transitive derefs because they are all callable on the type.

Web-sys has done this because it most closely mimics JavaScript inheritance, which you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement):

> Inherits properties from its parent, [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

You can traverse those in the same way, except `Object` is omitted because everything inherits from `Object`.

If you are writing native Rust code, you should not do this. Not only does this create huge, repetitive doc pages like here, it's also not true to the spirit of `Deref`, which should cheaply produce a reference to the value contained within a pointer type. This is only done in web-sys because its types are actually in JavaScript.

Instead, implement [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), which you can implement as many times as you like, doesn't clutter your method namespace or docs, and doesn't hold the strict meaning of `Deref`.